# jsGrid with multple data sources

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

I have a jsGrid where I want to display data from a database table with multiple foreign keys, so some of the fields of the grid's data are foreign keys referring to different sources: to do so I have written the following

```
$(function() {
    $.when(
      $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/datasource1/"}),
      $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/datasource2/"})
    ).then(
      (data1, data2) => {
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            // irrelevant options for the grid
            controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/griddata/",
                        data: filter
                    });
                },
                insertItem: function(item) {...},
                updateItem: function(item) {...},
                deleteItem: function(item) {...}
            },
            fields: [
                { name: "foreign1", title: "FK1", type: "select", width: 100, items: data1, valueField: "id", textField: "value" },
                { name: "foreign2", title: "FK2", type: "select", width: 100, items: data2, valueField: "id", textField: "value" },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

From what I understand, `when` should wait for both ajax calls to retrieve their data, and then render the grid. Unfortunately, i can see the rows in the grid, but no value for those fields, neither the foreign key nor the corresponding value on the `data1` or `data2` arrays (which both are retrieved correctly).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, for me the solution was that the data from the loadData function needs to return just the 'valueField', rather than the whole object.

In this case loadData should return this:

```
[{foreign1:1,foreign2:1},...]
```

Not this:

```
[{foreign1:{id:1, value:"one"},foreign2:{id:1, value:"one"},...]
```